# How to run total phase data center without being super user for the beagle I2C analyzer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to run the beagle I2C analyzer from total phase on Ubuntu 16.04 without being super user.  When I run it with sudo I'm able to see the beagle USB device, when I run it as my user I get the error "device is not found".

I've installed the linux udev rules and it appears they are working as the device is world read/writable.

```
$ lsusb | grep -i beagle
Bus 001 Device 083: ID 1679:2001 Total Phase Beagle Protocol Analyzer
$ ls -la /dev/bus/usb/001/083
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 189, 82 Oct 25 20:20 /dev/bus/usb/001/083
```

Any tips on how to run Data Center and connect to the analyzer without being superuser?

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem! I had set LIBUSBTP for libusb comparability issues I had been having per: http://www.totalphase.com/support/articles/200349996-libusb-compatibility-on-Linux which was causing the issue.

I ran strace on the program as superuser and as myself and the diff of those two revealed that I was using the 32-bit binaries as my user which was causing the problem.  I unset LIBUSBTP and the application is running as my user.

Total Phase Version: aardvark-api-linux-x86_64-v5.15

==== As my user ====

```
$ strace -ttvfo /tmp/aadetect.log -s 1024 sudo python aadetect.py
write(1, "Detecting Aardvark adapters...\n", 31) = 31
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

==== As root ====

```
$ sudo strace -ttvfo /tmp/aadetect-sudo.log -s 1024 python aadetect.py
write(1, "Detecting Aardvark adapters...\n", 31) = 31
open("/dev/bus/usb", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

==== Fix ====

```
$ echo $LIBUSBTP
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4
$ unset LIBUSBTP
$ echo $LIBUSBTP

$ python aadetect.py 
Detecting Aardvark adapters...
1 device(s) found:
    port = 0   (avail)  (2238-385546)
```